# JavaScript: Generate random number in range on click and add random number on every next click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got to make script that should generate random number from 1 to 10 on element click and every next click that variable should be higher than previous generated number.

There is my code, I just need to add that "adding next random number to previous generated random number". I'm stuck there a little bit :-)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#wheel-start').click(function () {
    var min = 1;
    var max = 10;
    var totalDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    $('#wheel-rotate').css({
      'transform': 'rotate(' + totalDegree * 72 + 'deg)'
    });

    console.log('totalDegree: ' + totalDegree);
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if the first number is 9 or 10?

Comment: Doesn't matter what the first number is.

Comment: "*and every next click it should be higher than previous*"

Comment: Edited the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the `min` with the newly generated number. But once it reaches the upper limit, you can't get any other number other than the max range.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#wheel-start').click((function(min, max) { 
       return function() {
          var totalDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
          min = totalDegree;
          max = min === max ? (max+10) : max;

          $('#wheel-rotate').css({
             'transform': 'rotate(' + totalDegree * 72 + 'deg)'
          });
          console.log('totalDegree: ' + totalDegree);
       }
    })(1, 10));
});
```

Comment: min will be set as 1 on every click. Because of "var min = 1;" line. You have to move "var min = 1" to out of function scope.

Comment: Also, you need to update `max` as well, otherwise you'll only be generating that number.

Comment: @muratonnet Updated it to work correctly. Thanks for pointing it though.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah. I did mention that. OP has to tell the requirement. Do you what exactly his requirement is?

Comment: After 10 that returns only 10 cause of max limit, how to upgrade the limit?

Comment: * every next click on element

Comment: @chepkasov Upgrade the limit to what? I will just update the code to upgrade the limit to another 10. You can modify it as per your requirement later.

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you, you're the best! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Just save `totalDegree` in a higher scope and increment its value each click:

```
function clickCallback(){
    var min = 1;
    var max = 10;
    var plus = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    totalDegree += plus;
```

}

Change min and max to define a smaller/bigger random step

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var n=0;

  $('#wheel-start').click(function () {
  var min = 1;
  var max = 10;
  var go=true;
  while(go){
     var totalDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
     if(n<totalDegree){
        n=totalDegree;
        go=false;
     }
  }

  $('#wheel-rotate').css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + totalDegree * 72 + 'deg)'
  });

  console.log('totalDegree: ' + totalDegree);
  });
});
```

Have a nice day

Comment: This will turn into an infinite loop when `n = 10`

Comment: It's suffice add an "exception" to prevent it. My "solution" responds to the question and stop